# Cannot run AWS Data Pipeline job due to ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

I've written some CDK code to programmatically create a data pipeline that backs up a DynamoDB table into an S3 bucket on a daily basis.

But it keeps running into this error:

```
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Failed to complete EMR transform. at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.EmrActivity.runActivity(EmrActivity.java:67) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by:
....
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.HadoopJobRunner.executeCommand(HadoopJobRunner.java:175) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.mapreduce.HadoopJobRunner.ex
```

I'm using the `DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole` and `DataPipelineDefaultRole` for this data pipeline which has S3:* permission, so I'm puzzled why this is happening.

On top of that, I'm not sure why logging is not enabled on my EMR cluster which is spun off by this data pipeline although I've specified the logLocation parameter: `myLogUri`

Any pointers please?

```
import { CfnPipeline } from "monocdk/aws-datapipeline";

private createDataPipeline(props: InfrastructureStackProps) {
            const dataPipelineName = "a-nice-datapipeline8.23";
            const pipeline = new CfnPipeline(this, dataPipelineName, {
                name: dataPipelineName,
                parameterObjects: [
                        {
                              id: "myDDBTableName",
                              attributes: [
                                {
                                  key: "Description",
                                  stringValue: "Source table"
                                },
                                {
                                  key: "Type",
                                  stringValue: "String"
                                },
                                {
                                  key: "Default",
                                  stringValue: "Attributes"
                                }
                              ]
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myOutputS3Location",
                          attributes: [
                            {
                              key: "Description",
                              stringValue: "Output S3 Location"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Type",
                              stringValue: "String"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Default",
                              stringValue: "s3://ddb-table-backup/"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myDdbReadThroughputRatio",
                          attributes: [
                            {
                              key: "Description",
                              stringValue: "DynamoDB Read Throughput Ratio"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Type",
                              stringValue: "Double"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Default",
                              stringValue: "0.15"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          id: 'myLogUri',
                          attributes: [
                            {
                              key: 'type',
                              stringValue: 'AWS::S3::ObjectKey',
                            },
                            {
                              key: 'description',
                              stringValue: 'DataPipeline Log Uri',
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myDDBRegion",
                          attributes: [
                            {
                              key: "Description",
                              stringValue: "Region of the DynamoDB Table"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Type",
                              stringValue: "String"
                            },
                            {
                              key: "Default",
                              stringValue: props.region
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ],
                      parameterValues: [
                        {
                          id: "myDDBTableName",
                          stringValue: "Attributes"
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myOutputS3Location",
                          stringValue: "s3://ddb-table-backup/"
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myDdbReadThroughputRatio",
                          stringValue: "0.15"
                        },
                        {
                          id: 'myLogUri',
                          stringValue: `s3://data_pipeline_log/`,
                        },
                        {
                          id: "myDDBRegion",
                          stringValue: props.region
                        }
                      ],
                pipelineObjects: [
                    {
                        "id": "EmrClusterForBackup",
                        "name": "EmrClusterForBackup",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "resourceRole",
                                "stringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "role",
                                "stringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultRole"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "coreInstanceCount",
                                "stringValue": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "coreInstanceType",
                                "stringValue": "m4.xlarge"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "releaseLabel",
                                "stringValue": "emr-5.29.0"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "masterInstanceType",
                                "stringValue": "m4.xlarge"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "region",
                                "stringValue": props.region
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "type",
                                "stringValue": "EmrCluster"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "terminateAfter",
                                "stringValue": "2 Hours"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "S3BackupLocation",
                        "name": "S3BackupLocation",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "directoryPath",
                                "stringValue": "s3://ddb-table-backup/"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "type",
                                "stringValue": "S3DataNode"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "DDBSourceTable",
                        "name": "DDBSourceTable",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "readThroughputPercent",
                                "stringValue": "0.15"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "type",
                                "stringValue": "DynamoDBDataNode"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "tableName",
                                "stringValue": "Attributes"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "Default",
                        "name": "Default",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "failureAndRerunMode",
                                "stringValue": "CASCADE"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "resourceRole",
                                "stringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "role",
                                "stringValue": "DataPipelineDefaultRole"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "scheduleType",
                                "stringValue": "cron"
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'schedule',
                                refValue: 'DailySchedule'
                            },
                            {
                                  key: 'pipelineLogUri',
                                  stringValue: 's3://data_pipeline_log/',
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "type",
                                "stringValue": "Default"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Every 1 day",
                        "id": "DailySchedule",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": 'type',
                                "stringValue": 'Schedule'
                            },
                            {
                                "key": 'period',
                                "stringValue": '1 Day'
                            },
                            {
                                "key": 'startDateTime',
                                "stringValue": "2021-12-20T00:00:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "TableBackupActivity",
                        "name": "TableBackupActivity",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "key": "type",
                                "stringValue": "EmrActivity"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "output",
                                "refValue": "S3BackupLocation"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "input",
                                "refValue": "DDBSourceTable"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "maximumRetries",
                                "stringValue": "2"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "preStepCommand",
                                "stringValue": "(sudo yum -y update aws-cli) && (aws s3 rm #{output.directoryPath} --recursive)"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "step",
                                "stringValue": "s3://dynamodb-dpl-#{myDDBRegion}/emr-ddb-storage-handler/4.11.0/emr-dynamodb-tools-4.11.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDBExport,#{output.directoryPath},#{input.tableName},#{input.readThroughputPercent}"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "runsOn",
                                "refValue": "EmrClusterForBackup"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "resizeClusterBeforeRunning",
                                "stringValue": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                activate: true
            });
            return pipeline;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be avoiding the direct issue at hand here, but I'm curious to know why you are using DataPipeline for this? You would probably be better served using [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorksAWS.html) which will allow you to take periodic backups in a manged fashion as well as other features such as expiring backups or sending to cold storage.

On the particular issue at hand, please check that your S3 bucket does not have a resource based policy blocking you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html

Also check the EC2 role used for your DP, commonly called `AmazonEC2RoleforDataPipelineRole`. More info on IAM roles for DP [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html).

Comment: No, Data Pipeline is designed for such a use case. And thanks, my S3 bucket doesn't have any policy blocking me and I'm just using the default `AmazonEC2RoleforDataPipelineRole`.

Comment: Data Pipeline *WAS* designed for such a use-case but has long been superseded with AWS Backup Service, DynamoDB Export to S3 and AWS Glue, all of which consume no capacity from the DynamoDB table unlike DP. Not to mention the lower operational overheads provided by all of these services.

Comment: This debate should probably happen in a different place instead of under this OP.